# How long could a shark breathe pepsi?

Tags: marine-biology, breathing

Sharks breathe seawater. Seawater isn't 100% pure water, but mostly water. Pepsi (other colas are available) isn't 100% pure water, but mostly water.

How long would a shark be able to breathe if submerged in Pepsi (other colas are available) and what, precisely, would kill them?

Comment: I don't think the dissolved $\ce{CO2}$ would do them any favours. And I doubt the chemicals from the cola would be very good for the shark (caffeine is toxic to many animals).